# passing info from window to window using wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

The program should have a a mainwindow and a second window where the mainwindow contains the datagrid. However, I can't seem to find a way where I can transfer the data from the client window to the datagrid in the mainwindow and we are not allowed to use any form of database in this program.

here is the code for mainwindow

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<string> intlist = new List<string>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public MainWindow(List<string> intlist)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.intlist = intlist;
        foreach (string x in intlist)
        {
            lstView.Items.Add(x);
        }
    }

    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Client x = new Client();
        x.Show();
    }
```

and the code for the client window is here

```
public partial class Client : Window
{
    List<string> intlist = new List<string>();
    public Client()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Client(List<string> intlist)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.intlist = intlist;
    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.intlist.Add(NameTB.Text);
        MainWindow x = new MainWindow();
        x.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

and this is my xaml for mainwindow

```
    <Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lstView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="209" Margin="86,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="635">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="Add" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="86,304,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Click="Add_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

and my xaml for client window

```
<Window x:Class="Proj_example.Client"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Proj_example"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Client" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="NameTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="66" Margin="117,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="566"/>
    <Button x:Name="save" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="66" Margin="117,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Click="save_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Jake, please do not post pictures of your code, as stated in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), people won't be able to run the code on their side if you only provide pictures of it. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60683472/edit) your question and replace them with a code block like you did for your two last code extracts!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You can then simply use the MainWindow instance to access the MainWindow `intList`

Like this (in `save_Click` Method)

```
MainWindow x = new MainWindow();
x.intList.Add(NameTB.Text);
```

**Option 2:**

Your MainWindow has a constructor that takes a list as a parameter.
You then have to pass the list to the constructor as

Like this (in `save_Click` Method)

```
this.intlist.Add(NameTB.Text);
MainWindow x = new MainWindow(intlist);
```

Comment: what doesn't work and why? the new item are not added to the MainWindow intList? can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: the items from client window still wont the display

Comment: did you try the second option?

Comment: how do I do the binding on this?

Answer (score 0):

1). You aren't actually sending your list to your Client dialog

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    //Client x = new Client();
    //You need to provide the list
    Client x = new Client(intlist);
    x.Show();
}

public Client(List<string> intlist)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.intlist = intlist;
}
```

2). You are creating a new master window instead of opening the one that is already there. You can pass a reference to your first window and just call show(), or even better, learn to use events and have your Client call an OnSaveEvent that MainWindow subscribes to which can handle saving the record, closing Client and showing itself.

```
private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.intlist.Add(NameTB.Text);
    //this is a new instance of main window with it's very own list.
    MainWindow x = new MainWindow();
    x.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

3). And finally, if you get all that working, you aren't actually telling the view that the data has been updated. For this you will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `MainWindow`.